# How to use pg_restore on Windows Command Line?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, heroku

I have downloaded a PG database backup from my Heroku App, it's in my repository folder as latest.dump

I have installed postgres locally, but I can't use pg_restore on the windows command line, I need to run this command: 
`pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -j 2 -h localhost -d DBNAME latest.dump`

But the command is not found!

Answer (score 8):

Since you're on windows, you probably just don't have pg_restore on your path.
You can find pg_restore in the bin of your postgresql installation e.g. c:\program files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin.

You can navigate to the correct location or simply add the location to your path so you won't need to navigate always.